# Tinyint better to use or not

Tags: sql, performance, paging

I have a question. Is tinyint better to use or not with a 64 bit OS.
The Paging on this would be of 64 bit and not 8. And thus tinyint will consume same memory as int(4 byte).
How does it actually makes a difference?

Its for all language or db.

Comment: tinybit? do you mean tinyint? and what database server are we talking about?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best answer to performance questions like these is

**Measure. Don't guess.**

1. Choose one or more dbms. (They don't
   all work the same.)
2. Build a mock-up of your database
   using tinyint.
3. Build another mock-up using
   integers.
4. Load both with sample data.
5. `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`
   queries on both databases.

Come back and tell us what you found. (You might be surprised.)

Answer (score 0):

of course a tinyint is faster / smaller than a bigint.

smaller datatypes allow more pages per row, the data is smaller.. indexes are smaller.

it's a BIG deal.